# Change language without restarting activity

Tags: android, fragment, locale

I have a method that translates my application from English to Swedish and back again if the user so wishes. However, I don't really like the fact that the activity restarts every time because it's giving me a hard time with the `savedInstaceState` and I've had several crashes because of this.

Here's how my method that changes language looks:

```
public void setApplicationLanguage(String language) {
    myLocale = new Locale(language);
    Resources res = activity.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics display = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration configuration = res.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(configuration, display);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(activity, StartupActivity.class);
    activity.startActivity(refresh);
}
```

Is there any chance that the same function can be applied without the:

```
Intent refresh = new Intent(activity, StartupActivity.class);
activity.startActivity(refresh);
```

?

Comment: put that method in OnResume method that works.

Comment: In the fragments onResume or in the activity's onResume? Because the method want's a String @SAVVY.

Comment: you can make the string global for that class so you can  get  or set that string

Comment: you can make a single tone class and get and set the data and put the method in onresume method

Comment: The Activity Class has a method called `recreate();` Use that and instead of starting the activity that way!

Comment: Just give me a minute, gonna rewrite some code and try this out.

Comment: @Xenolion well this did work ... but I get this in the logcat: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null. The app does not crash though. But it's written in red as a warning.

Comment: Recreate just recreate an activity fast !

Comment: The log cat happens because the Activity was recreated! and reference to previous activity was removed!

Comment: If you like the solution let me answer it official then!

Comment: This still calls the onCreate-method in the Activity right?

Answer (score 13):

## Try this

- I also had this issue.I used the code below and then it changed the language without refreshing the activity

---

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {

myLocale = new Locale(lang);
Resources res = getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = myLocale;
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
onConfigurationChanged(conf);
/*Intent refresh = new Intent(this, AndroidLocalize.class);
startActivity(refresh);*/
  }

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  // refresh your views here
    lblLang.setText(R.string.langselection);
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
// Checks the active language
if (newConfig.locale == Locale.ENGLISH) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else if (newConfig.locale == Locale.FRENCH){
    Toast.makeText(this, "French", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
  }
```

---

- declare in Manifest `android:configChanges="locale"`

Comment: When you say "refresh you views here" Im not sure what to do, because I have a whole fragment with 4 string resources that gets translated from english to swedish and the opposite around. So what am I supposed to do in the //refresh your views here - when the method I showed in my question does the job for me?

Comment: How to set title for **ViewPager** in your `// refresh your views here` code block@VishalYadav

Comment: in `<activity...`

Comment: use this `android:configChanges="locale"` inside your activity tag

Answer (score 1):

**You can replace the code:**

```
Intent refresh = new Intent(activity, StartupActivity.class);
activity.startActivity(refresh);
```

**With the method from Activity class:**

```
recreate();
```

I hope your minimum SDK version will support because it was introduce in SDK 11. Your activity will be recreate as a new instance remember! Everything will be started afresh. From my experience it is fast compared to making a new `Intent`. But if you want to pass some data the method of using `Intent` is better than that! You can add extras to the `Intent`.

Comment: Don't you get the question, It's been asked **Change language without restarting activity**. Try to answer what has been asked then after you can add extra information.@Xenolion

Comment: This has been so old, You have downvoted it. Okay then it is hardly possible to change the language without restarting the activity, otherwise implement the logic to change the String values to another strings of different language @MaulikDodia . So do you have an answer? Answer it!

Comment: I'm also having same problem. What I'm concern is, although you have understood the question your answer is completely opposite without mentioning what you have mentioned in above comment like `Okay then it is hardly possible to change the language without restarting the activity`. If you have put this line in answer then only your answer looks like **You don't have exact solution but have alternative one**.@Xenolion

Comment: It has been months since I answered that, Have you seen this line in the user's question?? Is there any chance that the same function can be applied without the: that is what my answer is based on! So what should I do by then? Comment and go? @MaulikDodia Atleast the one who asked find it useful and upvoted it.

Comment: That doesn't matter when you answered. You must answer what has been asked. If you don't have exact answer you must give clarification for why are you giving an **ALTERNATIVE** solution. There tons of solutions available which are not appropriate to question asked on SO. Which leads to time wasting and misleading. @Xenolion

Comment: Okay then answer it then @MaulikDodia

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton class:

```
public class Singleton {
   private static Singleton mInstance = null;

   private int repeat = 0;

   public int getRepeat() {
      return repeat;
   }

   public void setRepeat(int repeat) {
      this.repeat = repeat;
   }
}
```

Now you have a method that you can set and get the data, so make a method and put it under `onResume()` method, call your method and you can get and set the data like this:

```
Singleton.getInstance().setRepeat(1);
Singleton.getInstance().getRepeat();
```

Comment: Not sure that I follow. Just want to point out that I really appreciate that you are trying to help me.